# Pandas: Multiple Grand Totals in a Summary Dataframe

Tags: numpy, pandas, dataframe, plyr, aggregation

Apologies for the noob question as I try to learn Python.  Looking forward to getting up to speed and giving back

Assuming I have the following data,

```
YEAR         SECTOR    PROFIT   STARTMVYEAR TOTALPROFIT STARTMV
IBM         TECHNOLOGY  -500    2500        500         1500
APPLE       TECHNOLOGY   800    4000        300         4500
GM          INDUSTRIAL   250    1000          0         1250
CHRYSLER    INDUSTRIAL   600    3000        100         3500
```

I want to create a summary that looks as follows

```
SECTOR      PROFITYEAR  TOTALPROFIT
TECHNOLOGY     .046       .133
INDUSTRIAL     .213       .021
```

Where for each group, we have `sum(PROFIT)/sum(STARTMVYEAR)` and `sum(TOTALPROFIT)/sum(STARTMV)`

If I wanted to do it for just the first benchmark, I could do

```
by_profit_totals =(df.groupby(['SECTOR'])['PROFIT'].sum()/by_first_count.groupby(['SECTOR'])['STARTMVYEAR'].sum())
```

But how do I do it for both?  Also, is there is easy function I could use that takes, for example, profit and startmvyear and returns the summary value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`cython optimized`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and then [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) by `numpy array` created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
g = df.groupby('SECTOR').sum()
print (g[['PROFIT','TOTALPROFIT']].div( g[['STARTMVYEAR','STARTMV']].values).reset_index())
       SECTOR    PROFIT  TOTALPROFIT
0  INDUSTRIAL  0.212500     0.021053
1  TECHNOLOGY  0.046154     0.133333
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Glad I can help you. Nice day!